# converting Num to Fractional in Haskell

Tags: haskell, int, tuples, double

Basically I have some exercises to learn tuples in Haskell.

In this one I declare a type named StudentMark which requires:

- A String (the name of the student)
- Int (the mark of the student, 0 to 100).

Then I have to create a function which caps the mark of a student to a maximum of 40.

But I get this error doing it:

```
No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’
```

I think it is related with I being returning a double instead of an Int but I cannot figure out how to fix this. Here is the code:

```
import Data.Char

type StudentMark = (String, Int)

{- the total mark without cap would be 100, with the cap it would be 40,
  if we divide 100/40 we get 2.5 which is a common factor
-}
capMark :: StudentMark -> StudentMark
capMark (std, mrk) = (std, fromIntegral (mrk / 2.5))
```

Comment: Since a `StudentMark` is a tuple of a `String` and an `Int`, that does not seem to make much sense here. You should actually aim to convert it back to an `Int`, or just leave it an `Int`, like `(std, div (mrk * 4) 10)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it is related with I being returning a double instead of an Int but I cannot figure out how to fix this.

Not exactly, in Haskell, there are no implicit conversions.

Since `StudentMark` is in fact an alias of `(String, Int)` that means that `mrk` is an `Int`. But your division [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-) takes as type a `Fractional a`, and an `Int` is not a member of the `Fractional` typeclass. For integral divisions, one can use [**`div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:div)

We can thus write this like:

```
capMark :: StudentMark -> StudentMark
capMark (std, mrk) = (std, div (mrk * 4) 10)
```

or a shorter version with [**`second :: Arrow a => a b c -> a (d, b) (d, c)`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:second):

```
import Control.Arrow(second)

capMark :: StudentMark -> StudentMark
capMark = second ((`div` 10) . (*4))
```